# postgreSQL: how to duplicate a row

Tags: postgresql

This is the scheme of my table web_book:

```
     Column     |          Type          |                       Modifiers                       
----------------+------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------
 id             | integer                | not null default nextval('web_book_id_seq'::regclass)
 page_count     | integer                | not null
 year_published | integer                | not null
 file           | character varying(100) | not null
 image          | character varying(100) | not null
 display_on_hp  | boolean                | not null
 name           | character varying(128) | not null
 description    | text                   | not null
 name_cs        | character varying(128) | 
 name_en        | character varying(128) | 
 description_cs | text                   | 
 description_en | text                   |
```

The table contains one row with `id=3`. I want to duplicate the row but If I try this:

```
INSERT INTO web_book SELECT * FROM web_book WHERE id=3;
```

I get this:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "web_book_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(3) already exists
```

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You need to create a new ID for the newly inserted row:

```
INSERT INTO web_book( 
   id, page_count, year_published, file, image, 
   display_on_hp, name, description, name_cs, 
   name_en, description_cs, description_en
)
SELECT nextval('web_book_id_seq'), 
       page_count, 
       year_published, 
       file, 
       image, 
       display_on_hp, 
       name, 
       description, 
       name_cs, 
       name_en, 
       description_cs, 
       description_en 
FROM web_book WHERE id=3;
```

As mentioned by ClodoaldoNeto you can make things a bit easier by simply leaving out the ID column and let the default definition do its job:

```
INSERT INTO web_book( 
   page_count, year_published, file, image, 
   display_on_hp, name, description, name_cs, 
   name_en, description_cs, description_en
)
SELECT page_count, 
       year_published, 
       file, 
       image, 
       display_on_hp, 
       name, 
       description, 
       name_cs, 
       name_en, 
       description_cs, 
       description_en 
FROM web_book WHERE id=3;
```

In this case you don't need to know the sequence name (but it is a bit less obvious what's going on).

Comment: @clime Since the `nextval` is the default for the `id` column it is not necessary to declare it. `INSERT INTO web_book( 
   page_count, ...) SELECT page_count, ...`

Comment: @clime: It's not only simpler to let the default kick in, it also avoids additional errors later on. If you go behind your sequence and add the next `id` manually, the sequence is not incremented. One of the next rows relying on the default will probably draw a number from the sequence that's already duplicated by the manual `INSERT`. Don't do this or get your sequence in sync afterwards - for instance with [`setval()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-sequence.html).

Comment: Is it possible to change one value ? like choose a different name rather than what is returned from the select query ?

Answer (score 16):

Specify `id` column only if you specify its value (and it's not your case). You want to use next sequence `web_book_id_seq` value, so do not specify it in your INSERT query.

Your INSERT should looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO web_book (page_count, year_published, file, image, display_on_hp, name, description, name_cs, name_en, description_cs, description_en)
SELECT page_count, year_published, file, image, display_on_hp, name, description, name_cs, name_en, description_cs, description_en
FROM web_book
WHERE id = 3;
```

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes when there are lots of columns you might want avoid copy-pasting all column names.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp (like web_book);
INSERT INTO tmp SELECT * FROM web_book WHERE id = 3;
UPDATE tmp SET id = nextval('web_book_id_seq');
INSERT INTO web_book SELECT * from tmp;
```

Comment: I think this makes the `nextVal` and `insert` statements not a single atomic operation, i.e. it's possible that you get the same `duplicate key` error.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative.

Notice that in this example, prtkey and pubkey are binary fields using bytea type.
The uptime is a timestamptz not null field.

```
INSERT INTO keysvc (id,title,pvtkey,pubkey,status,uptime) VALUES( 2, 'ramnode4',null ,null ,1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

with keys as (SELECT pvtkey, pubkey, uptime FROM keysvc where id = 1)
update keysvc set pvtkey=(select pvtkey from keys), pubkey=(select pvtkey from keys), uptime=(select uptime from keys) where id =40;
```