# how to "deepcopy" rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15429756/postgresql-how-to-duplicate-a-row) but more involved. Suppose I have a table `A` with id `idA`, and another table `B` with `idB` and foreign key `idA`. I would like to duplicate all entries of A, including corresponding entries in B. For example, if I have the following tables at the start:

```
A
|---|
|idA|
|---|
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
|---|

B
|---|---|
|idB|idA|
|---|---|
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
|---|---|
```

Then the result should be:

```
A
|---|
|idA|
|---|
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
|---|

B
|---|---|
|idB|idA|
|---|---|
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 4 |
| 6 | 5 |
|---|---|
```

Comment: You can copy rows with `INSERT INTO b SELECT b.* FROM a JOIN b ... WHERE ...`.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite tricky.  You need to insert the ids into the `a` -- but then be able to match them back to the existing ids to insert the right values into `b`.

A generic solution looks like this:

```
with i as (
      insert into a
          select . . .  -- the other columns you want
          from a
          order by idA
          returning *
     ),
     a_mapping (
      select a.idA, i.idA as new_idA
      from (select a.*, row_number() over (order by idA) as seqnum
            from a
           ) a join
           (select i.*, row_number() over (order by idA) as seqnum
            from i
           ) i
           on a.seqnum = i.seqnum
     )
insert into b (idA) (
    select am.new_idA
    from b join
         a_mapping am
         on b.idA = am.idA;
```

Note:  If you have another unique column or columns in the row, then the mapping is a little easier to generate.  Of course, if you are copying all the columns, then nothing else is unique, so you do need the `row_number()`.

Of course, for your very simple example, you don't need a mapping table.  You can just use:

```
with i as (
      insert into a
          select . . .  -- the other columns you want
          from a
          order by idA
          returning *
     )
insert into b (idA) (
    select i.idA
    from i
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this seems to contain syntax errors that I can't hammer out :(

Comment: I've written an answer with my current approach, if you have time to check it out!

Answer (score 0):

I have an approach which may be equivalent to what Gordon Linoff suggests, I would be grateful if you could point out any flaws!

Let's set up the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE A(
    idA SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
    txt varchar);

INSERT INTO A(txt)
VALUES ('A1'), ('A2'),('A3');

CREATE TABLE B(
    idB SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
    idA int REFERENCES A(idA), 
    txt varchar);

INSERT INTO B(idA, txt)
VALUES (1, 'A1.B1'), (1, 'A1.B2'), (2, 'A2.B1');
```

so the initial data looks as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM (A LEFT JOIN B ON A.idA=B.idA) ORDER BY A.idA, B.idB;


 ida | txt | idb | ida |  txt  
-----+-----+-----+-----+-------
   1 | A1  |   1 |   1 | A1.B1
   1 | A1  |   2 |   1 | A1.B2
   2 | A2  |   3 |   2 | A2.B1
   3 | A3  |     |     | 
(4 rows)
```

Now, we can use the `NEXTVAL` function to generate the mappings directly:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_A_new AS (
    SELECT *, NEXTVAL('A_idA_seq') as newidA 
    FROM A ORDER BY idA -- order probably not needed
);
INSERT INTO A(idA, txt) (SELECT newidA, txt FROM tmp_A_new);

CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_B_new AS (
    SELECT B.idB, newidA, B.txt, NEXTVAL('B_idB_seq') as newidB 
    FROM B, tmp_A_new WHERE B.idA=tmp_A_new.idA ORDER BY idB 
);
INSERT INTO B(idB, idA, txt) (SELECT newidB, newidA, txt FROM tmp_B_new);
```

The results look correct:

```
SELECT * FROM (A LEFT JOIN B ON A.idA=B.idA) ORDER BY A.idA, B.idB;


 ida | txt | idb | ida |  txt  
-----+-----+-----+-----+-------
   1 | A1  |   1 |   1 | A1.B1
   1 | A1  |   2 |   1 | A1.B2
   2 | A2  |   3 |   2 | A2.B1
   3 | A3  |     |     | 
   4 | A1  |   4 |   4 | A1.B1
   4 | A1  |   5 |   4 | A1.B2
   5 | A2  |   6 |   5 | A2.B1
   6 | A3  |     |     | 
(8 rows)
```

Note that this could be continued further down to C, D, etc.

I would be glad for any comments :)