# PostgreSQL : How to duplicate row for certain number?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a sample table like this

```
col1    col2    col3    num1    num2
------------------------------------
val1    val2    val3     1       5
val4    val5    val6     7       15
val7    val8    val9     18      26
```

I want the row become as many as the difference between num2 and num1. For example, I want the first row to be 4 rows (5 - 1 = 4).

Expected result:

```
col1    col2    col3    num1    num2
------------------------------------
val1    val2    val3     1       5
val1    val2    val3     1       5
val1    val2    val3     1       5
val1    val2    val3     1       5
val4    val5    val6     7       15
val4    val5    val6     7       15
val4    val5    val6     7       15
val4    val5    val6     7       15
val4    val5    val6     7       15
val4    val5    val6     7       15
val4    val5    val6     7       15
val4    val5    val6     7       15
val7    val8    val9     18      22
val7    val8    val9     18      22
val7    val8    val9     18      22
val7    val8    val9     18      22
```

Referring to the answer here [postgreSQL: how to duplicate a row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15429756/postgresql-how-to-duplicate-a-row), is it possible to duplicate without primary key? or PK is absolutely needed? Then what is the most effective way to achieve this? I'm thinking about using for loop as general programming, but I believe there's a simpler way using SQL

Comment: Can you post your expected result as well?

Comment: @JimMacaulay edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use generate_series() for that:

```
select t.*
from the_table t
  cross join generate_series(t, d.num2 - t.num1)
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=307ed8b21739bd99e02b10d706e5ef01)

If you want to insert those rows into the table, put an `INSERT` in front of it:

```
insert into the_table(col1, col2, col3, num1, num2)
select t.*
from the_table t
  cross join generate_series(1, t.num2 - t.num1)
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5b041337cee9ec3c30331898d7e5b521)

To include negative difference (num2 < num1) and remove unnecessary original row

```
insert into the_table(col1, col2, col3, num1, num2)
select t.*
from the_table t
  cross join generate_series(1, abs(t.num2 - t.num1) - 1)
```

Comment: If you want  to insert the rows, then put an `insert` in front  of the select (see my edit)

Comment: Thanks a lot, sorry I didnt include this in the sample, but what if my row has float number like this `num1=261.8 num2=262.5`. I expect the row will be 7 as the difference is 7. I changed the `1` to `0.1` but it gave me wrong result

Comment: Nevermind, I got it right after reading the documentation. I changed the `int` to `float` or `numeric`, then change cross join line to `cross join generate_series(1, (t.num2 - t.num1)*10)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursive CTE to generate the duplicate rows and then an `INSERT...SELECT` query to insert them:

```
WITH RECURSIVE CTE AS (
  SELECT col1, col2, col3, num1, num2, num1 + 1 AS cnt
  FROM data
  UNION ALL
  SELECT col1, col2, col3, num1, num2, cnt + 1
  FROM CTE
  WHERE cnt < num2 - 1
)
INSERT INTO data
SELECT col1, col2, col3, num1, num2
FROM CTE
;
SELECT *
FROM data
ORDER BY col1
```

Output

```
col1    col2    col3    num1    num2
val1    val2    val3    1       5
val1    val2    val3    1       5
val1    val2    val3    1       5
val1    val2    val3    1       5
val4    val5    val6    7       15
val4    val5    val6    7       15
val4    val5    val6    7       15
val4    val5    val6    7       15
val4    val5    val6    7       15
val4    val5    val6    7       15
val4    val5    val6    7       15
val4    val5    val6    7       15
val7    val8    val9    18      22
val7    val8    val9    18      22
val7    val8    val9    18      22
val7    val8    val9    18      22
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c7647/1)

Comment: Thank you, if I change the `SELECT col1, col2, col3, num1, num2` to `SELECT *` but it gives me error, do you know the reason behind that?

Comment: There is an extra column in the CTE (cnt) which doesn't belong in the table, so you can't use `SELECT *`